# Azure function not executing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have written an Azure function based on a blob trigger. When I try to run that Azure function, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down. Azure.Storage.Queues: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value').

Below is the Azure function code

```
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("productdata/{name}", Connection = "appSetting")] Stream myBlob, string name)
  {
      _logger.LogInformation("Function starting at: {Timestamp}", DateTime.Now);

      var excelDataList = ExcelParser.ReadExcelToObjects<ProductModel>(myBlob);
      var usedProductList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      var listOfJson = new List<string>();

      try {
          _telemetryClient.TrackEvent($"Start processing number of records: {excelDataList.Count()}");

          foreach (var excelData in excelDataList) {
              string productNameCode = string.Empty;
              bool isFoundProductCode = false;
              string jsonData = string.Empty;

              int uniqueRandom = UniqueRandomGenerator.GenerateUniqueRandom();

              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelData.ProductName)) {
                  if (usedProductList.Count > 0) { 
                      if (usedProductList.Keys.Any(x => x == excelData.ProductName)) {
                          productNameCode = usedProductList[excelData.ProductName];
                          GenerateProductCode(productNameCode, excelData);
                          isFoundProductCode = true;
                      }
                  }

                  if (!isFoundProductCode) {
                      productNameCode = uniqueRandom.ToString();
                      GenerateProductCode(productNameCode, excelData);
                      usedProductList.Add(excelData.ProductName, productNameCode);
                  }

                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelData.ProductCode) &&
                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelData.Division) &&
                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelData.Type) &&
                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelData.Status)) {
                      Product product = new Product(excelData);
                      jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
                      string accessToken = await _restClient.GetAccessTokenAsync(Config.OAuthUrl,
                          await _secretProvider.GetSecretAsync(Config.KeyVaultClientIdName),
                          await _secretProvider.GetSecretAsync(Config.KeyVaultClientSecretName));
                      _restClient.AccessToken = accessToken;
                     await _restClient.PostAsync(GetEntityUrl(), product);

                      
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      _logger.LogWarning($"Missing a required fields data: ProductName:{excelData.ProductName}, Type: {excelData.Type}," +
                          $" ProductGroup: {excelData.ProductGroup}, DeliveryMethod: {excelData.DeliveryMethod}");
                  }
                  
              }
          }

          _telemetryClient.TrackEvent($"Finished processing");
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {
          _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
          _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
      }
  }
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",    
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "82cc67f0-2ff6-4920-a202-953ea0c84313"
      }
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Please post your code and how you are triggering it.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: I have update the question with code

Comment: Have you debugged to find out what value is null? and also checked for null checks in the possible object, eg check the myBlob converting to ProductModel all the associated values are present.

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same error, when I ran a simple blob trigger functions code,

[image]

I changed my **local.settings.json** like below,

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "appSetting": "<Storage_Connec_string>"
  }
}
```

Then, I run a simple blob trigger function and it runs  successfully as below,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, now I am getting another error that "Azure.Core: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Http: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10000). System.Net.Sockets: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." Could you help here

Comment: The error you are facing because the target machine actively refused, typically indicates that your application is trying to connect to a service running on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) at port 10000. Still, no service is listening on that port.
Check whether the IP Address and port are correct or not. 
If you're working in an environment with a proxy server, ensure that your application's proxy settings are configured correctly